# How to determine when document has loaded after loading external css

Tags: javascript, css

How to determine when document has loaded(or is loading) after loading external css?

Normal page has loaded and complete at first time(with using `document.onreadystatechange` or `document.readyStage`), but after time script will call function to place a new stylesheet CSS into HTML for changing a background or images. During change stylesheet, document has still stage complete. Stage never has been changed after calling function? Why?

Timeline(example):

1. Visit one page : localhost/index.html
2. Document has stage loading
3. Document has stage complete
4. User was trying to change a theme, at this time stage hasnt been changed yet.

**UPDATE**: Without jQuery:)

**UPDATE**:
Example problem with using one image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> 

    <script>
        document.onreadystatechange = function(){
            console.log(document.readyState);
        };
        function checkDocumentState(){
            console.log(document.readyState);
            return setTimeout(function(){ 
                checkDocumentState();
            }, 1000);
        }
        checkDocumentState();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="" onclick="this.setAttribute('src','http://i.imgur.com/uRBtadp.jpg')" style="width:50px; height:50px; background-color:gray; " /> Press empty image and open new image.
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

**FOUND ANSWER:** [How can I tell when a CSS background image has loaded? Is an event fired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285809/how-can-i-tell-when-a-css-background-image-has-loaded-is-an-event-fired)

But hopeless .. lack of universality...

Comment: "loaded" and "loading" are not the same. once it's done, it's done. you can probably monitor the dynamic link tag somehow.

Comment: what are you trying to do that's a problem?

Comment: Get changes from document state ;) State "complete" should be back to "loading", because of big images are gonna to load. I am trying to determine it, and page shows up as "loading page". U can understand it?

Comment: readyState will never roll backwards. once complete, you'll have to monitor your own resources individually. in short, after onload(), loading state is more complex than a single global value can indicate...

Comment: U can place example code? How to monitor all resources from CSS, which are needed to view. (font-face and background-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this code, what i wanted and worked for me:

```
window.engineLoading = {images_count:0, images_loaded_count:0, fonts_count:0, fonts_loaded_count:0 };
document.querySelector("a").onclick = function(){ // first elemnet a
    var before_stylesheets_length = document.styleSheets.length;
    var before_fonts_size = document.fonts.size;

    document.fonts.onloadingerror = function(a){
        window.engineLoading.fonts_loaded_count++;
    }               
    document.fonts.onloading = function(a){
        window.engineLoading.fonts_count++;
    }       
    document.fonts.onloadingdone = function(a){
        window.engineLoading.fonts_loaded_count++;
    }

    var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var style= document.createElement('link');
    style.rel= 'stylesheet';
    style.setAttribute("href","./new_style.css");
    style.onload = function(){
        for(i=before_stylesheets_length; i<document.styleSheets.length; i++){
            var rules = document.styleSheets[i].rules;
            for(q=0; q<rules.length; q++){
                var styles = rules[q].style;
                for(s=0; s<styles.length; s++){
                    console.log(styles[s]);
                    if((styles[s] == "background-image" || styles[s] == "background") && styles.backgroundImage.length > 0){
                        window.engineLoading.images_count++;
                        var body= document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
                        var image = document.createElement('img');
                        var url = styles.backgroundImage;
                        url = url.replace(/^url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, '');
                        image.src = url;
                        image.width = 0;
                        image.height = 0;
                        image.setAttribute("class","pace-load-style");
                        image.onload = function(e){
                            console.log(e);
                            window.engineLoading.images_loaded_count++;
                        };
                        image.onerror = function(e){
                            window.engineLoading.images_laoded_count++;
                        }
                        body.appendChild(image);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    style.onerror = function(){};
    head.appendChild(style);


    setTimeout(function(){ 
        checkCurrentState();
    }, 1000);
    return false;
};

    function checkCurrentState(){
        if(window.engineLoading.images_count == window.engineLoading.images_loaded_count && window.engineLoading.fonts_count == window.engineLoading.fonts_loaded_count){
            console.log("loaded"); return true;
        }console.log("still loading...");
    return  setTimeout(function(){ 
            checkCurrentState();
        }, 1000);
    };
```

**UPDATE**: Scipt has bug on localfile because of empty rule. [CSSRules is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961544/cssrules-is-empty) I don't worry about it , and no need fix it.

**UPDATE**: Mozilla Firefox hasnt reference document.fonts.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is called after DOM elements are populated. This is why in the days of dial up internet, the page would load all funky looking, and then all of a sudden start to develop into the desired page bit by bit. I would suggest using Jquery instead, where you could use the following code to be able to ensure the document is fully loaded and the CSS is already implemented

```
$document.ready(function() {
//Insert Code here
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: CSS linked in the head is loaded and parsed BEFORE html is layedout

Comment: I beg to differ dandavis. The html is what the browser will have on hand first, and start populating it first. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6500141/do-external-stylesheets-get-loaded-before-the-html

Comment: layout. the page will not be _shown_ until css is ready, so the showing of un-styled content you describe can not happen. unless you import a sheet from the end of the body...

Comment: $document.ready(function(){}) - is once time called by document state complete. But after state complete i wanna place new stylesheet, state must be changed to loading(or loaded) because images are gonna to load. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp

Comment: jQuery is a bit overhead for this, don't you think?

Comment: I am using jQuery too, but isn't the most tool for it based on document stage.

Comment: You've got a point there about Jquery being overboard. Listen to them, not me.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question, how to determine the document has loaded after dynamically loading a css file depends upon the different browser vendors out there. There is not a single sure shot way for all the browsers, but lets tackle the problem one by one for each of these browsers.

**Preface**

```
var url = "path_to_some_stylesheet.css",
    head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    link = document.createElement('link');

link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet"
link.href = url;
head.appendChild(link);
```

Once that appending is done:

- **Internet Explorer** : fires [readystatechange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536957%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and `load`.
- **Opera** : fires load event via `onload`.
- **Chrome** : Doesnt fire an event but increments `document.styesheets.length` only **after** the file has arrived.
- **Firefox**: I was not able to reliably get anything other than [mozAfterPaint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/MozAfterPaint).

Comment: I know about document.stylesheets and onLoad, problem is how to determine all files, which are really loading by placing new css (example: body{background-image:url("new_image.png")}).